# Replace in front of found element in string

Tags: javascript

I have this string :

```
"{ \"username\": \"{{email}}\",\"password\": \"{{password}}\"  }"
```

And i would like to add in front of each key a break line, like this :

```
"{\n\t\"username\": \"{{email}}\",\n\t\"password\": \"{{password}}\"\n}"
```

How can i do it with .replace(), since i'm using it

I'm trying this code :

```
.replace(/( \"[a-z]\":)/g,"\n\t");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative without `replace` is parsing the string and then using the function `stringify` which adds the necessary `\n`.

```js
let js = JSON.parse("{ \"username\": \"{{email}}\",\"password\": \"{{password}}\"  }");
console.log(JSON.stringify(js, null, 3));
```